# Quickbook Desktop Development Basics

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I've been asked to develop some software for a friend who has a business that he manages using Quickbooks Desktop. I don't have Quickbooks Desktop, and I'm not quite sure how to get started. I've read the docs for about a week now and can't seem to figure out the first step.

From what I've read, it seems like maybe the Quickbooks application starts a web server and mine application will be issuing HTTP requests against that web server ? It would be nice if I didn't have to have the Quickbooks application to do this development; is there a way to read the data file itself ? Does it cost money to develop software that uses this API ?

It looks like I would probably like to use the V2 XML protocol for what I'm trying to do which is: retrieve checks and deposits, make a monthly summary, format that summary according to his specifications, and create a PDF of the statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> From what I've read, it seems like maybe the Quickbooks application
>   starts a web server and mine application will be issuing HTTP requests
>   against that web server ?

That's one possible way to implement things.

If you give more detail about specifically what you're trying to do (what programming language? what version of QuickBooks?) you'll probably get better recommendations than that route.

> It would be nice if I didn't have to have the Quickbooks application
>   to do this development; is there a way to read the data file itself ?

You will have to have QuickBooks, there's no way to read the raw datafile.

It's cheap on Amazon - buy it there.

> Does it cost money to develop software that uses this API ?

There are no charges while developing, and for one-off/custom/in-house integrations like you're talking about, there are no charges at all.

> It looks like I would probably like to use the V2 XML protocol for what I'm trying to do which is:

Be aware that v2 and v3 is technically only for SaaS applications (e.g. you have to be reselling this as an app, and allowing many people to connect their QuickBooks to your app).

According to Intuit, you should be using the [SDK](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits/0250_qb).

Comment: Great. Thanks a good deal for your answers. I don't care which language, but would probably prefer Java. I noticed in the SDK that c-sharp has the QBFC which doesn't appear to have an equivalent in Java. I don't know what version of QB he has. What other way is there to query the data rather than make QB a web server ? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: The core QuickBooks SDK APIs are all Windows COM based APIs. QBFC is an object-based wrapper around the core COM API. If you're integrating from a website, the Web Connector is probably the easiest way to go (http://wiki.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_web_connector). If you're building a Windows desktop app, C# with the SDK is usually pretty easy to deal with, and there are examples in the SDK.